# Allow relaying for a group of users but disallow sender-addresses other than the Primary SMTP Address of the user

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange-2013

I need to allow a **specific group of authenticated exchange users** to relay emails using SMTP. Those users must be **disallowed to relay emails using a different sender address**, than their assigned primary SMTP address.

I have been looking for only a hint, but I haven't even found someone asking the same question.

How do I achieve this on Exchange 2007? Or maybe on Exchange 2010/2013? Configuration could be similar, if not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could see to do this, if the resources are there for you to do so, would be to use a completely separate domain (or separate UPN of your primary domain) and in your Send Connectors Add that separate domain (or UPN) to a new rule allowing relaying.

Using an alternate UPN (that is something to incorporate at the AD level) and the method I described above you would need to ensure all users using that alternate UPN domain name have it set as their default Email Address in the Recipient Configuration section of EMC, and you would also need to uncheck "Automatically update email addresses based on email address policy" as well as delete the primary domain from their "email addresses" as to not allow the relaying from the primary address.

I've been able to incorporate this structure in an Exchange 2010 environment with success.